# difference between IAuthenticationFilter and IAuthorizationFilter in asp.net webapi 2?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, difference

We can achieve Basic authentication feature using AuthorizationFilterAttribute which uses IAuthorizationFilter Interface itself as below,

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute  
{  
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)  
    {  
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)  
        {  
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            // Gets header parameters  
            string authenticationString = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;  
            string originalString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationString));  

            // Gets username and password  
            string usrename = originalString.Split(':')[0];  
            string password = originalString.Split(':')[1];  

            // Validate username and password  
            if (!ApiSecurity.VaidateUser(usrename, password))  
            {  
                // returns unauthorized error  
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);  
            }  
        }  

        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);  
    }  
}
```

Then why should we use IAuthenticationFilter and Attribute for basic authentication as below,

```
public class BasicAuthenticator : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{


    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context,
                                  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(
                     HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context,
                            CancellationToken cancellationToken) {}
}
```

I am new to these concepts in asp.net webapi 2, Please mention when to use AuthorizationFilterAttribute and when to use IAuthenticationFilter and Attribute for Basic authentication. Good Answer would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: In case you missed it in the documentation, Reference [Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Hi Nkosi, thanks for your reply :), i will go through document and get back

Comment: See also [Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)